# Flutter Firebase change password of user with 2FA enabled

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, multi-factor-authentication

When i sign in with 2FA (email provider, phone provider) i just do **signInWithEmailAndPassword**, then i catch **FirebaseAuthMultiFactorException**, get **MultiFactorResolver** to resolve second factor and sign in successfully. Similar for sign up.
The problem arises when i try to modify user data, like to change password.

I tried the same flow as we do for sign in/ sign up flow, but it doesn't work, it returns **FirebaseException** instead of **FirebaseAuthMultifactorException**:

```
Future<void> changePassword({required String email, required String password, required String newPassword}) async{
    final user = _firebaseAuth.currentUser!;
    try{
      final cred = EmailAuthProvider.credential(email: email, password: password);
      await user.reauthenticateWithCredential(cred);
    } on FirebaseAuthMultiFactorException catch(e){
      log("i need to get resolver here but this line is never executed");
    } on FirebaseException catch(e){
      log("firebase exception, which doesn`t provide resolver");
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

The output is following:

```
[log] firebase exception, which doesn`t provide resolver
E/flutter (18929): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_auth/second-factor-required] Please complete a second factor challenge to finish signing into this account.
E/flutter (18929): #0      parseMultiFactorError (package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:106:5)
E/flutter (18929): #1      platformExceptionToFirebaseAuthException (package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:49:14)
E/flutter (18929): #2      convertPlatformException (package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:23:5)
E/flutter (18929): #3      MethodChannelUser.reauthenticateWithCredential (package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_user.dart:181:7)
E/flutter (18929): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (18929): #4      User.reauthenticateWithCredential (package:firebase_auth/src/user.dart:452:7)
E/flutter (18929): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (18929): #5      AuthRepository.changePassword (package:vendor/repositories/auth/auth_repository.dart:43:7)
E/flutter (18929): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (18929): #6      new AuthBloc.<anonymous closure> (package:vendor/blocs/auth_bloc/auth_bloc.dart:50:7)
E/flutter (18929): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (18929): #7      Bloc.on.<anonymous closure>.handleEvent (package:bloc/src/bloc.dart:226:13)
E/flutter (18929): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Comment: Note: i think this is flutter firebase-sdk problem, because sdk for android native and swift are both throwing FirebaseAuthMultifactorException with resolver, but flutter not throwing any resolver to help that

Answer (score 0):

That was flutter firebase-sdk issue that was fixed since firebase_auth 4.1.0.
**Changelog:**
FIX: properly propagate the FirebaseAuthMultiFactorException for all reauthenticate and link methods (#9700). (9ad97c82)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).